# List Generation in Lisp

Tags: list, lisp, heap-memory, sbcl

Why do people say lists come for free in Lisp?

If I run this code

```
(let ((acc '()))
       (do ((i 1 (incf i)))
           ((= i 100))
         (do ((j 0 (incf j)))
         ((= j 100))
           (do ((k 0 (incf k)))
           ((= k 100))
         (do ((l 0 (incf l)))
             ((= l 100))
           (do ((m 10 (+ 10 m)))
               ((= m 500))
             (let ((unfiltered (copy-list '(0 0 0 0 0))))
               (setf (nth 0 unfiltered) i)
               (setf (nth 1 unfiltered) j)
               (setf (nth 2 unfiltered) k)
               (setf (nth 3 unfiltered) l)
               (setf (nth 4 unfiltered) m)
               (push unfiltered acc))))))))
```

I get a heap exhausted error in SBCL. I'm not very familiar with how Lisp works under the hood, but I need to generate a list of very many lists. Is there a way to do that without running out of heap space?

Thanks

Comment: How about buying a computer which supports more lists?

Comment: Why not use a multidimensional array?

Comment: Ok, I'm up for that, but I guess, I'm not sure how that would be different storage wise than using a list of lists..(sorry if this is a basic question)

Comment: It works fine if you have more than 400GB RAM. How are you going to use the list?

Comment: I am doing a reinforcement learning problem. In order to do value iteration I need to represent the entire state space. The problem is actually fairly complex and the state space is extremely large

Comment: How big is the state space? Is it sparse? Do you need it fully populated?

Comment: Pretty sizeable...I haven't been able to enumerate it. We are trying to do RL in an open source game, 0ad. We have a state vector with 50 ish features. An example feature is # of infantry. A possible value is 10, which represents 0 - 10 infantry units. The graph is not sparse.

Comment: I don't suppose I need the entire state space loaded in memory at once. If its possible, I'd like to load in bits and pieces of it as needed.

Comment: Who are these people that say "lists come for free"? I have never heard anyone say that about Lisp, except perhaps in the sense that they're built-in. They're certainly not free in the "doesn't use any storage" sense.

Comment: Only incidental to your question, but you don't want to use (incf i) in the updates of a DO over i, etc..  That's the same as doing (setq i (+ i 1)).  The i is already going to be updated by the do, and you need only supply the update, which is (+ i 1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
> Why do people say lists come for free in Lisp?
```

No idea.

It seems you need a mental idea of how lists are stored in memory. This makes you able to compute how much space the lists will need.

A cons cell consists of two slots. A list like `(a b c)` is stored as `(cons 'a (cons 'b (cons 'c '())))`. A simple model is to think of a cons cell as two pointers. The first pointer in (cons 'a ...) points to the symbol. The second pointer points to the next cons cell. The cons cell thus uses two 64bit-words. For lists of small numbers, the number can be stored directly in the cons cell, so a list of numbers `(list 1 2 3)` uses 4 64bit-words.

Given this you should be able to compute how much space your example needs.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're having is that you're trying to create 100*100*100*100*50 lists of 5 elements each, that's 5 billion lists with 25 billion elements in total. Long story short, it doesn't fit in the amount of memory assigned to lisp image. It's likely that it won't fit even if you assigned your whole memory to lisp.

**EDIT:**
Let's calculate some best case lower bounds.

The `acc` list contains 5 billion elements, that's 5 billion *cons cells*.

Maximum amount of memory 32bit computer can address is 4GiB, so 32bit is out of question. 64bit computers can use much more, but that also means that our pointers are going to be twice as long.

Each *cons cell* must have at least 2 64bit (8 byte) pointers. Additionally, each cons cell must have some indication that it's a *cons cell*, flags for garbage collector, maybe flags for null values etc. Let's pretend that we can squeeze those in one byte. One of our *cons cells* can therefore fit into 1 + 2 * 8 bytes = 17 bytes of memory.

5 billion * 17 bytes = 85 billion bytes ~= **79GiB of memory required**

Each of those 5 billion lists contains 5 *cons cells*:

25 billion * 17 bytes = 425 billion bytes ~= **396GiB of memory required**

And finally, each of those 25 billion cells contains one integer. Those are long ints in your case, but with proper declaration, you could perhaps squeeze them in one byte on some implementations plus one byte for type indication, except for the last `m` variable, that'd have to be two bytes + type indication. Therefore each list's integers take up at least

4*2 + 3 bytes = 11 bytes per list for storing integers.

5 billion lists * 11 bytes = 55 billion bytes ~= **51GiB memory required**

In total, this adds up to at least **526GiB of memory space** and all assigned to Lisp interpreter - just to store your data, not counting lisp image itself, OS, etc. It also requires optimized integers and optimized implementation that can do it in those tight conditions.

**There's a solution:**

1. Buy couple of terabytes of SSD's
2. Assign it as swap
3. ????
4. Profit...

**And for quitters or sane people, there's one cheaper solution:**
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation